# Retrofit2 POST method gets code 400 but works with Restlet Client

Tags: java, json, post, retrofit2, okhttp

I am using Retrofit2. I want to POST some data to my Web Service from my mobile device but always get code 400 response. When I try to send a POST request from Restlet Client, I get normal response (chrome-extension://aejoelaoggembcahagimdiliamlcdmfm/restlet_client.html#requests).

I got some info that the problem could be in server certificate so I implemented OkHttpClient but I still get the same result. 
If I try to POST to jsonPlaceHolder I get a normal result (https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts)

API INTERFACE:

```
public interface JsonPlaceHolderApi {

@POST("hws/hibisWsTemplate/api/v1/order/posts")
Call<Post> createPost(@Body Post post);
}
```

MY POST CLASS:

```
public class Post {
private String vodilni_slog;
private String IBAN_placnka;
private String polog;
...

public Post(String vodilni_slog, String IBAN_placnka, String polog) {
    this.vodilni_slog = vodilni_slog;
    this.IBAN_placnka = IBAN_placnka;
    this.polog = polog;
    ...
}

//getters and setters
 ...
```

}

MAIN ACTIVITY(only a part where I send a POST request):

...

```
send_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       //RETROFIT
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = getUnsafeOkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("https://xxxxxx.x-xx.xx/") //url
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            jsonPlaceHolderApi = retrofit.create(JsonPlaceHolderApi.class);


         Post post = new Post("test", "test", "test", "test");

         Call<Post> call = jsonPlaceHolderApi.createPost(post);

         call.enqueue(new Callback<Post>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<Post> call, Response<Post> response) {

                        if (!response.isSuccessful()) {
                            MainActivity.content.setText("Code: " + response.code());
                            return;
                        }
                        Post postResponse = response.body();

                        String x = "";
                        x += "Code: " + response.code() + "\n";
                        x += "Naziv: " + postResponse.getIme_prejemnika() + "\n";
                        x += "IBAN: " + postResponse.getIBAN_prejemnika() + "\n";
                        x += "Sklic: " + postResponse.getReferenca_prejemnika() + "\n";

                        MainActivity.content.setText(x); 
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<Post> call, Throwable t) {
                        MainActivity.content.setText(t.getMessage());
                    }
                });
            }
    });
```

OKHTTP CLIENT:

```
private static OkHttpClient getUnsafeOkHttpClient() {
    try {           
        final TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
                new X509TrustManager() {
                    @Override
                    public void checkClientTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void checkServerTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType) throws CertificateException {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
                        return new java.security.cert.X509Certificate[]{};
                    }
                }
        };

        final SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
        sslContext.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());

        final SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = sslContext.getSocketFactory();

        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        builder.sslSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory, (X509TrustManager)trustAllCerts[0]);
        builder.hostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
            @Override
            public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                return true;
            }
        });

        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = builder.build();
        return okHttpClient;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

I expect code 201 with body:
{
  "vodilni_slog": "string",
  "polog": "string",
  "dvig": "string",
   ...
{

but I get code 400...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out that I have been getting error 400 because IBAN_placnka should have been iban_placnka so if you are getting error 400 check your spelling and use this line to see what you are actually getting in json format:

```
Log.e("x" , "Request is" + new Gson().toJson(post).toString() );
```